# Calculate monthly Avg of daily percentage values

Tags: powerbi, dax

We have a report in `Compliance%` which is calculated every day. I have a requirement to calculate the Monthly Average of these daily `Compliance%` values.

PowerBI currently gives incorrect total value in a table format, I have attached the sample file. It is giving 56.90 in the grand total whereas I want to calculate `sum(Compliance%)/count(day or month)`.

Could someone please help.

[[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to introduce a new measure:

```
mDay = 
    IF(
        HASONEFILTER(Table1[Compliance %]),
        SUM(Table1[Day]),
        FORMAT(
            SUMX(Table1, Table1[Compliance %]) / COUNT(Table1[Day]), 
        "0.00%")
    )
```

Here's the result for the month of February:

[image]

Here's another one if you also include a few values from March:

[image]

As you can see the measure responds to your table filters.
I hope it helps.